# What is Hadoop's getProgress() method in TaskStatus class?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

The class `TaskStatus` class has a method `getProgress()` but I am not sure on what this method actually returns.

Is it the time that was spent or is it input data that was processed?

I want to know how much data was processed until now in the source code. What should I do? Should I use `getProgress()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the JavaDoc comment from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.facebook.presto.hadoop/hadoop-apache2/0.1/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/StatusReporter.java#StatusReporter)

> Get the current progress.
>
> **Returns**: a number between 0.0 and 1.0 (inclusive) indicating the attempt's progress.

Attempt being the mapreduce job here.

Comment: how can I get the input data size of each map or reduce task ?

Comment: @mndn I don't know of any function that calculates the exact size, but, for mapper the size of input data will always be less than the split size which you can calculate using `FileInputFormat.computeSplitSize()`

Comment: TaskStatus class has a method getPhase(). what does it return?(are they only map, shuffle, sort, reduce?)

Comment: @mndn It can return anything from `STARTING, MAP, SHUFFLE, SORT, REDUCE, CLEANUP` depending on he current `Phase` which is an enum.

Comment: I need to call FileInputFormat.computeSplitSize() in defualtSpeculator.java,it need k,v (FileInputFormat<k,v>).How I can do that ?

Comment: @mndn AFAIK, this `<K, V>` denotes Java's `Generics`. You don't need to pass those `K` and `V`. Just `import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat` and you should be able to use `computeSplitSize`

Comment: you mean I should write FileInputFormat<k,v>.computeSplitSize() ?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. Once you have imported the class, you can call the function just by it's name. It should be `computeSplitSize` only

Comment: I could not.I add a photo of what I did to the top question.

Comment: @mndn I suggest you ask a different question for that.

Comment: I asked, my latest question .would you please answer there.thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255386/how-can-i-get-the-input-data-size-of-each-map-or-reduce-task