# how can I get the input data size of each map or reduce task?

Tags: hadoop

[image]I need to know input data size of each task .Which class in hadoop can help me?
is `FileInputFormat.java` helpful ?how to use it?
it needs some input,What are they?

Comment: Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291170/how-does-hadoop-process-records-split-across-block-boundaries/34737075#34737075

Comment: how can I make an object from  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.fileinputformat<k,v> to use getsplit() method?

Answer (score 0):

The input size of the whole task is just the size of input files from hdfs.

The input size of eack mapper task is calculated according to the following propertiy (64 is the default size) :

```
mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize=64Mb
```

Hadoop splits the input into pieces of size `split size`, which is equal to:

```
max(mapred.min.split.size, min(mapred.max.split.size, dfs.block.size))
```

Use this property get the size of your input.

Comment: hadoop has logical split and physical split.the physical split is for hdfs ,but the logical split is for a task.maybe one task needs to process more than one physical block.

Comment: I need the input data for task.